# YouTube playlist contains videos with playback restrictions, but no reason what the restriction is

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have noticed that many of the videos that I added to my favorites and playlists on YouTube do not show up when trying to view these on my Sony Blu-Ray player that has a YouTube app.

When trying to view on my PlayStation 3, I get a message like:

> This playlist does not appear to contain videos without playback restrictions

I can't find any information about why they are restricted on these devices and not on my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know the answer to this. When the user uploads a video, they can choose whether or not that particular video can be viewed on a mobile device. If they choose NO (which the default when uploading a video is YES) then it can only be views on YOUTUBE itself from what I understand. I'm running into this problem as well with a playlist I've created. And it doesn't make sense why the user would have chose no only on a particular video, but not the rest. It's up the the person who uploaded the video to allow it to be viewed on a mobil device such as bluray, ps3 etc.

Comment: I think this is correct.  I've never had the issue on Google TV.  I think this is because Google TV uses Chrome and therefore does not have to be considered a mobile device.  Or Chrome on Google TV is filtering out the restricted videos so I never encounter them.  I've since stopped using PS3 for everything except games.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a PS3 so this is only a guess, but have you set up parental restrictions on your PS3 which you don't have on your PC.

Thus the PC plays everything, but the PS3 is blocking some videos because they're "too old".

The other alternative is that the PS3 You Tube app has this built in and you can't change it.

**UPDATE**

After re-reading your comment I wonder if the videos have content that violates Sony's (or who ever the service provider is for your phone) terms of use or licensing. This would explain why they are blocked on these devices but not on your PC.

Comment: The issue is not only with the PS3.  It's also with the Youtube app on my internet connected Blu ray player and also with the Youtube app on my Android phone.  I am guessing it's a licensing issue where youtube cannot play certain content on these types of devices.  But this doesn't really make sense to block it if it can be viewed on the PC.  Maybe the content providers for the videos that are blocked think advertisements (which are a shared revenue stream with Google) will not be displayed like on a PC.